# How to translate/use 一巧

Tags: meaning

All of a sudden in my course we've started using "一巧" everywhere, and I really do not understand it at all.

example:

尽管我很喜欢这张唱片，可是我一巧也开始喜欢它，想到以后可以跟一巧一起听音乐，我决定把这张唱片给他。

which I understand all of, except how to translate the 一巧

EDIT:
My apologies, there was a typo in the sentence. Fixed now. I had mistyped 也 as 页, and forgot the rest of the sentence.

Comment: speak chinese for 30 years,do not understand it at all,either.

Comment: From the last part of the sentence, 一巧 seems to be the name of a person. The middle part doesn't make any sense, probably some typo errors. Best is to consult your teacher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typo aside, there are a few grammatical issues with your sentence.

1. (Mis)use of the 尽管...可是... construction. This conjunctional
   construction, like in English (even though/notwithstanding),
   indicates a condition/status, preceded by 尽管 and a second condition
   that indicates a *contrast* to the first, usually indicated by
   adverbs like 却, 但还是, 也要, and very rarely, 可是. In your example, the
   second condition seems to be a complementary/favourable condition to
   the first or simply a statement, rather than a contrast.
2. The phrase 我一巧也开始喜欢它 makes no sense at all. My guess is that you
   are simply trying to tell people that '一巧' (whoever that is) also
   started to love the album. 开始喜欢 is grammatically sound in Mandarin
   (assuming this is the flavour of Chinese you are learning), but it
   does sound a little awkward to my ears. A better way to express this
   would be 渐渐地喜欢上. I am not certain what you are trying to describe with 我一巧, but if you insist on using this structure, then might I suggest 我的一巧. 我的一巧 (my 一巧) is used to indicate a very intimate relationship between you and 一巧, to the extent of a romantic relationship. I can only assume that 一巧 is male, because you used the pronoun (他) in the second sentence (even though it sounds more female than male).
3. Lastly, this should really be split into two sentences

Here is my attempt at reconstructing the sentence and my take on its meaning:

> 我很喜欢这张唱片，就连我的一巧也渐渐地在喜欢上它。 想到以后可以跟一巧一起听音乐，我决定把这张唱片给他。
>
> I really love this album; even my yiqiao is beginning to like it. Realizing that I can listen to music together with yiqiao from now on, I decide to give this album to him.

Comment: Oh goodness. Thank you. This was a sentence from my chinese professor and I was absolutely baffled by the 一巧 bit, since this is the first time we've heard this name, AND 巧 is on our list of new words. This is all very good to know! Thank you~

Comment: @EricR I think the fact that he/she failed to explain the usage of 一巧 is baffling :).

Comment: `我的一巧` is an inspiring reconstruction. +1 for the awesome imagination.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a person's (and probably a girls') name, inferred from the last sentence.

But I don't think the 2nd part makes any sense, which may be corrupted by some typos.

Further context should be provided.

Comment: Added context. My apologies. Didn't copy the rest of the sentence over and there was a typo. However, it's good to know that's a name. I've been incredibly confused trying to translate it

Answer (score 1):

this sentence is wrong

if 一巧 is a name, it should be

尽管我很喜欢这张唱片，可是我**的**一巧也开始喜欢它，想到以后可以跟一巧一起听音乐，我决定把这张唱片给他。

or

尽管我很喜欢这张唱片，可是我一巧**弟弟**也开始喜欢它，想到以后可以跟一巧一起听音乐，我决定把这张唱片给他。